# javascript read before elements are rendered on web page

Tags: javascript

```
<button id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

External script file

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#btnSubmit');
btn.addListener('click', function(){
    alert('Loading...');
}, false);
```

I get

null is not an object evaluating btn.addEventListener

It is reading before the button is rendered.

It however works fine in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7enwttgq/

Comment: Jsfiddle may be giving you a false positive because of the nature of how it works. Where is your script in relation to your <button> tag in the HTML file? If the script is in the <head> or somewhere in the <body> before your button then the button does not yet exist when the script executes.

Comment: In the fiddle it works because the code runs in a `load` event handler. If in "Frameworks & Extensions" you choose "No wrap - in <head>", it won't work.